# Getting data between two date range in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I'm trying to fetch data between dates. The date select from date-picker. the formate is like this 04/13/2020 - 04/13/2020 select from date-picker. my query is like this

```
 public function reservation($reservation)
    {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('details');
    $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') > '$reservation'");

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope This will work for you

```
 public function reservation($first_date,$second_date)
 {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('details');
    $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') >='$first_date'");
    $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') <='$second_date'");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
 }
```

Comment: i'm selecting date from date-picker and thats like in  (04/13/2020 - 05/13/2020) format both date store in the same variable not in separate variable. like  $reservation="04/13/2020 - 05/13/2020";

Comment: not like $first_date=04/13/2020; $second_date=05/13/2020;

Comment: You can use explode function and separate both date in start date and end date

Example:
$str = "04/13/2020 - 05/13/2020";
print_r (explode("-",$str));
Output:
Array ( [0] => 04/13/2020 [1] => 05/13/2020 )

Comment: you need to edit your code according to the problem and it work for me after using explode function

Comment: @jamilshah: Sounds good it's work for you. You can up vote the answer so it will also help to others in future.

Comment: there is two arrow over there. you can click on above arrow in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d')",'>=',$first_date)
->where("DATE_FORMAT(end_date,'%Y-%m-%d')",'<=',$first_date);
```